# Firestone offline capabilities flutter

Tags: flutter

I know that Firestone will store data if the user is offline and I saw that there is a way to do this with native code, but is it possible to enable these offline capabilities in flutter itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase firestore support full offline. I’m using it myself. So long as you’ve read the data at least once before going offline. If using firebase authentication - the custom option also works offline. Google sign-in does not.

The downside to firebases offline capabilities is that it’s only firestore (not counting the older firebase db) and not the other products like cloud storage.

So for example I’ve written an app and the document side of it is fully offline enabled however you can take photos in the app and I had the write the offline capabilities to sync this photos with firebase cloud storage myself. 
(I basically just keep them in a pending folder and try to sync them when the device has connectivity.)